# What do the colors mean in job listings with the visa sponsor option?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

While going through the Developer Jobs section in Stack Overflow, for a few jobs under the job title I sometimes see "Paid Relocation" (in blue) and "Visa Sponsor" (in red). The Visa Sponsor option is usually not shown for most jobs listed. So what do the blue and red colors mean? Does the red "Visa sponsor" mean the company does NOT offer visa sponsoring? Does the blue color code mean something is available and the red color (or absence of an offering) mean it's not available?

Comment: OP, did my answer answer your question?

Comment: yes it did and I have marked it so :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those colors have no significance.

If a job has one of these things listed, that means it's included in the job offer. If it's not listed, it's not.

This is easily verified:

- Every mention of "Visa sponsor" is red.
- Every mention of "Paid relocation" is blue.
- Every mention of "Remote" is yellow.
- Every mention of "Equity" or a salary is blue.

This is the CSS responsible:

```
#job-detail .job-detail-header .-description .-perks .-salary {
    color: #5fba7d
}
#job-detail .job-detail-header .-description .-perks .-remote {
    color: #DFB82B
}
#job-detail .job-detail-header .-description .-perks .-visa {
    color: #F98C71
}
#job-detail .job-detail-header .-description .-perks .-relocation {
    color: #71a5cb
}
```

Comment: Every mention of "Equity" or a salary is `blue` -> `green`.